# Optimizing iteration over pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I was creating a dictionary (named data) using two columns of Data Frame (named sales_product ) using 'Sales Ord Id'(column name) as key and then inserting matching 'Prod ID'(column name)
to matching key list in dictionary.
But this program is taking nearly 6 hours to execute, so can anyone suggest any way make this process faster.

```
ID = []             #ID list
items = []
data = {}
for i in range(len(sales_product)):
    curr_id = sales_product['Sales Ord Id'][i] 
    if curr_id not in ID:
        ID.append(curr_id)
        data[curr_id]=[]
        data[curr_id].append(sales_product['Prod ID'][i])
    else:   
        if sales_product['Prod ID'][i] not in data[curr_id]:
            data[curr_id].append(sales_product['Prod ID'][i])
```

Comment: I suggest you to create a "secondary" dataframe with the data you need then use dataframe.to_dict() method, that's because operating with dataframe function is USUALLY more efficent than operating directly, specially if you use vectorization

Comment: But the problem here is i have to use 'Sales Ord Id' as key but it is not unique in my dataframe. I have to make a dictionary storing list of 'Prod ID' which have matching 'Sales Ord Id'  as key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use pandas [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). It groups a dataframe's data by a column values and lets you work with these groups. It should work faster.

```
import pandas as pd

sales_product = pd.DataFrame({'Sales Ord Id': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
                              'Prod ID': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 10]})

groupby = sales_product.groupby('Sales Ord Id')
data = dict([(x, list(d['Prod ID'])) for x, d in groupby])
print(data)
# prints {1: [11, 13, 15, 17, 19], 2: [12, 14, 16, 18, 10]}
```